# Android DecimalFormat doesn't format correctly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, decimalformat

I use `DecimalFormat` in a `TextWatcher`, here is my code:

```
override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            amountEt?.removeTextChangedListener(this)

            var df = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
            df.maximumFractionDigits = 2
            df.minimumFractionDigits = 0
            if (hasFractionalPart) {
                df.isDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown = true
            }
            try {
                val inilen: Int
                val endlen: Int
                inilen = amountEt?.text!!.length

                var text: String? = p0.toString().replace(df.decimalFormatSymbols.groupingSeparator.toString(), "")
                //text = text?.replace(df.decimalFormatSymbols.decimalSeparator.toString(), "")
                var n = df.parse(text)
                var t = df.format(n)
                val cp = amountEt?.selectionStart
                amountEt?.setText(t)
                endlen = amountEt?.text!!.length
                val sel = cp!!.plus(endlen - inilen)
                if (sel > 0 && sel <= amountEt?.text!!.length) {
                    amountEt?.setSelection(sel)
                } else {
                    // place cursor at the end?
                    amountEt?.setSelection(amountEt?.text!!.length - 1)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("ERROR", e.stackTrace.toString())
            }

            amountEt?.addTextChangedListener(this)
        }
```

My problem is that the user would like to write into the `amountEt` (this is an EditText) for example this: *1.02*

But when the user write the *zero* into my edittext, the `df.format(n)` line result will be *1*.

How can I solve this?

UPDATE:
I debugged my code and if I write 7.0 into the edittext I got this:

*text = "7.0"*

*n = 7* (type is Number)

If I change this line:

```
var n = df.parse(text)
```

to this:

```
var n = df.parse(text).toDouble()
```

*n = 7.0*

*t = "7."*

Here is an image about my debugger:
[image]

Comment: Could you try something like the following: `with(DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US)) {
        maximumFractionDigits = 2;
        minimumFractionDigits = 0;
        val n = parse("7.12");
        println(n);
        println(format(n));
    }` 
It prints "7.12, 7.12" for me. So the only difference is how ``DecimalFormat`` is created. I'm not sure if you really need the pattern?

Comment: I tried your code, it wrote the 7.12, I changed your code to use my text variable, but it wrote only 7 when I type into the edittext "7."

Comment: set `minimumFractionDigits = 1`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use DecimalFormat(**"#,###.00"**) instead of DecimalFormat("#,###.##")

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for convert to double

```
public static double Round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
        value = value * factor;
        long tmp = Math.round(value);
        return (double) tmp / factor;
    }
```

Comment: Its not problem for me to convert to Double, the problem is that the DecimalFormat format method cut off the 0 (zero)

Comment: I tried your method, this is working like the *toDouble()* method.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check below code for decimal format

```
public static String roundTwoDecimalsString(double d) {
        /*DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");*/
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        String formatted = df.format(d);
        return formatted;
    }
```

Comment: Thats okay, but I would like to use the grouping separator too. With your solution it does not work.